# How to dynamically populate a dependent dropdownlist based from the view item model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to update a list of data for a specific id and the list view have 3 columns. Say I have 6 rows on the List View, the 1st column is name the is the same on 6 records in the List View. 2nd column is Questions and the 6 questions are all different. The next column is Vision and this is a dropdownlist, on initial load the current record will the default value. This dropdownlist will be editable and each Question Columns has different set of dropdownlist based on the QuestionId attached to the VisionId. I don't know how to do it, please help. Thanks in advance

So here's my code EditAssessment on my controller. This will load my list view on my razor page.

```
    public IActionResult EditAssessment(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        IQueryable<Assessment> data = 
 _context.Assessment
            .Include(a => a.AsIs)
            .Include(a => a.Question)
            .Include(a => a.Vision)
            .Where(a => a.ProfileId == id);

        if (dataDividendToolContext == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }


        ViewData["Vision"] = new SelectList(_context.MaturityLevel, 
 "Description", "Description");

        return View(data .ToList());
    }
```

Here's my razor view codes, I don't know how to pass the Question as dynamic parameter to the Dropdownlist. Please note that the questions on the list view are all different so the dropdownlist should have different set of data.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Profile
        </th>
        <th>
            Question
        </th>
        <th>
            Vision
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Profile.ProfileName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
item.Question.QuestionDescription)
            </td>
            <td>
                <select asp-for="@item.Vision" class="form-control" asp- 
items="ViewBag.Vision"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: As i can understand, you have question id. Based on this, you need to update values of dropdown?

Comment: Hi Gaurav Chauchan, based on my ID I have the list of data displayed on my views. However I would like to the list to be editable but column Vision would be enabled for editing with a dropdownlist from my table based on the value of Question. The dropdownlist may have multiple set of data per rows based on the value of Question. Please help, thanks in advance